# How to serve csv files in my s3 bucket to a python app deployed on heroku

Tags: python, amazon-s3, heroku, plotly-dash

I have a python app (specifically a dash plotly dashboard) that I have deployed on Heroku. I have static files (csv/maps in the form of html etc.) that are input files for my app. However I am unable to get my python script to read these files when the heroku app starts.

I have already done the initial authentication piece of allowing heroku to access my aws bucket and set permissions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the steps are like this. This has to be a serverless application. Upon clicking the submit button on your website, an api should be called. Get/Post depending on your need.

(1)
An API will invoke a Lambda function that will take the csv file and store in s3.

Create a rest api using apigateway, connect with lamdba then store in s3.
You can use `boto3` library if you pick python for lambda.

(2) Another way, if you don't need to manipulate the data on backend. You can create an API that takes a file (less than 6mb) and stores directly to s3 bucket.

If you are familiar with terraform [this](https://github.com/ashraf-minhaj/AWS-IaCs-with-Terraform) might help.

Best wishes.